# Sort QStandardItemModel in c++ Qt

Tags: qt, sorting, model, qstandarditemmodel

I have a model of type QStandardItemModel which looks like this:

```
          QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames;
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::NameRole] =  "plate_number";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::DescriptionRole] = "address";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::FuelRole] = "fuel";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::InteriorRole] = "interior";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::ExteriorRole] = "exterior";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::VinRole] = "vin";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::LatRole] = "lat";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::LonRole] = "lon";
          roleNames[Car2goVehicle::DistanceRole] = "distance";
          d->m_vehiclesmodel = new RoleItemModel(roleNames);
```

and now I want to sort according to distance like this

```
           d->m_vehiclesmodel->setSortRole(Qt::UserRole);
           d->m_vehiclesmodel->sort(Car2goVehicle::DistanceRole, Qt::AscendingOrder);
```

But the result is wrong. Can somebody tell me how to sort ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with the result?
In most cases, one doesn't sort the model itself, but the view, using a [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qsortfilterproxymodel.html). Here's the example from the documentation:

```
QTreeView *treeView = new QTreeView;
MyItemModel *sourceModel = new MyItemModel(this);
QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);

proxyModel->setSourceModel(sourceModel);
treeView->setModel(proxyModel);
```

In your example above, you might mix up roles and columns. Your Role enum should look like this:

```
enum Role {
    NameRole=Qt::UserRole,
    DistanceRole,
    ...
};
```

If you want to sort by distance role, you call:

```
model->setSortRole( Car2goVehicle::DistanceRole );
```

Then, sort by some column (which has nothing to do with the role), E.g. column 0:

```
model->sort( 0, Qt::AscendingOrder );
```

Comment: You could even say, independently of how you sort your model the view might choose to display it in another way. That's why you need to use `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Comment: I have also used QSortFilterProxyModel but my model is sorted according to the Car2goVehicle::NameRole and not Car2goVehicle::DistanceRole

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using `QSortFilterProxyModel`, if `QStandardItemModel::sort()` is powerful enough. Instead, I stick use basic Qt signals.

Here, I'm using PyQt, but the code should also work in C++:

```
self.model = QStandardItemModel()
self.populate_model()
self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(map(str, range(self.model.rowCount())))
self.treeview.setModel(self.model)
self.treeview.header().setSectionsClickable(True)
self.treeview.header().setSortIndicatorShown(True)
self.treeview.header().sortIndicatorChanged.connect(self.model.sort)
```

Notice the last line connecting `QHeaderView::sortIndicatorChanged` with `QStandardItemModel::sort`.