# qt - how to permanently sort a qstandarditemmodel

Tags: c++, qt, sorting, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a program where I am trying to implement sorting on a qstandarditemmodel that is displayed in a table view.  However, the method I am using doesn't seem to actually sort the model itself, but only the view.  I need it to be able to sort the source model because I save the data to a .csv file using a delegate that passes the items from the model into an object of a class, and if the view is the only thing that is sorted it causes data loss due to the positions of the items in the view being changed but not in the model itself.

This is the code I use in the mainwidget constructor to connect the headerview clicked signal to a method that sorts the model:

```
currentStudentsModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);

ui->currentTableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);
ui->currentTableView->setModel(currentStudentsModel);

ui->currentTableView->setItemDelegate(currentStudentsDelegate);
currentTableHeader = ui->currentTableView->horizontalHeader();
connect(currentTableHeader, SIGNAL(sectionClicked(int)), this, SLOT(on_sectionClicked(int)));
```

Here is on_sectionClicked():

```
void mainWidget::on_sectionClicked(int index)
{
   currentStudentsModel->sort(index,Qt::AscendingOrder);
}
```

As I previously stated, this appears to only sort the items in the view as when I try to output all of the records stored in the model it has not changed from when they were initially entered.  How do I get the model to be sorted itself and that order to be saved?

Comment: How do you write data to `.cvs` file? Do you write this data directly from `currentStudentsModel` or do you use other data structure which you are using to populate `currentStudentsModel`?

Comment: @MarekR i take the the data from the `currentStudentsModel` and pass it into an object of a class called `CurrentStudent` which has data members that correspond to different columns of the model, i.e. data from the first column is passed into  `currentStudents[row].setFirstName()`, second column is last name, etc. I then have a function that writes all the data from every student object in a vector into .cvs format.

Comment: so I'm guessing you are creating `currentStudents` before sorting and writing `currentStudents` to `.csv` file after model was sorted, so you are writing unsorted data to file. Update `currentStudents` before saving (so it will be sorted) or rewrite saving code to directly save data from `QStandardItemModel`. Another "pro" approach is to abandon `QStandardItemModel` and implement own version `QAbstractTableModel`, but this is to hard for you.

Comment: @MarekR yeah I realized that I wasn't updating the currentStudents vector the other day and that's why it wasn't sorting, I'm just going to completely abandon using that as a class and write directly from the model like you suggested. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

QStandardItemModel does not implements sort.

### From Qt documentation:

> **void QAbstractItemModel::sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order =
>   Qt::AscendingOrder)**
>
> Sorts the model by column in the given order. The base class
>   implementation does nothing.

---

You need to sort through QSortFilterProxyModel

```
currentStudentsProxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
currentStudentsModel->setSourceModel( currentStudentsProxyModel );
currentStudentsProxyModel->sort( 0, Qt::AscendingOrder );

void mainWidget::on_sectionClicked(int index)
{
    currentStudentsProxyModel->sort(index,Qt::AscendingOrder);
}
```

Comment: He uses `QStandardItemModel` which does implement [sort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#sort).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731050/sort-qstandarditemmodel-in-c-qt

Comment: note he wrote: `However, the method I am using doesn't seem to actually sort the model itself, *but only the view*.`